# Differences between TableAttribute class in System.Data.Linq.Mapping and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF 6.1 where I was trying to get a simple sample code running. 
I accidentally used the namespace System.Data.Linq.Mapping (VS Intellisense) to realize the TableAttribute name parameter had no effect, the code created a new table (since POCO class name is different from table Name) when was executed. However, it was expected to use and existing table. 
Latter after few googling effort I noticed the namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation is used in some places. When I made this change, my sample started using the existing table rather than creating it.
I would like to know

- What is the difference between the TableAttribute class in these two namespaces?
- Why did the TableAttribute in System.Data.Linq.Mapping not yield the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute` belongs to LINQ to Entities.
- Entity Framework uses the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.TableAttribute`